How to express a constraint as percentage of selected items
I am new to OptaPlanner. I already written some code which works as expected.
enum Type {
    used,
    _new
}

public class Beam {

    private Long id;
    private Type type; // new or used
    private double length; 

    public Beam() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @param type
     * @param loanType
     * @param customerCategory
     * @param paymentMethod
     * @param region
     * @param length
     */
    public Beam(Long id, Type type, double length) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
        this.length = length;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}

@PlanningEntity
public class BeamSelection {
    private Beam beam;

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "booleanRange")
    private Boolean selected;  // true if the object is selected, false otherwise

    public BeamSelection() {
    }

    public BeamSelection(Beam beam) {
        this.beam = beam;
    }

    public Beam getBeam() {
        return beam;
    }

    public void setBeam(Beam beam) {
        this.beam = beam;
    }

    public Boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }
    
    public Boolean getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(Boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
}

@PlanningSolution
public class BeamSelectionSolution {

    private List<Beam> beamList;
    private List<BeamSelection> selectionList;
    private HardSoftScore score;

    // Provide the value range for the 'selected' variable (true or false)
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "booleanRange")
    public List<Boolean> getBooleanRange() {
        return List.of(true, false);  // Possible values for selection
    }

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    public List<BeamSelection> getSelectionList() {
        return selectionList;
    }

    public void setSelectionList(List<BeamSelection> selectionList) {
        this.selectionList = selectionList;
    }

    public List<Beam> getBeamList() {
        return beamList;
    }

    public void setBeamList(List<Beam> beamList) {
        this.beamList = beamList;
    }

    @PlanningScore
    public HardSoftScore getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(HardSoftScore score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
}


public class BeamSelectionConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {

    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return new Constraint[] { maximizeLength(constraintFactory), enforceUsedBeamsLengthRatio(constraintFactory) };
    }

    private Constraint maximizeLength(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        // @formatter:off
        return constraintFactory.from(BeamSelection.class)
            .filter(BeamSelection::getSelected) // Check if the object is selected
            .groupBy(sum(s -> (int) s.getBeam().getLength()))
            .filter(totalLength-> totalLength > 6000)
            .penalize("Max length exceeded", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD);
       // @formatter:on
    }
}

I would like to add an additional constraint: the total length of the selected used beams should be less than 35% of the total length of all the selected beams.
The constraint should be similar to the previous one but I don't know how to calculate the length of the used beams.
I tried different solutions but without any success.
Please, point me in the right direction.
Second question, is there any way to get rid of BeamSelectionSolution and move the selected field directly to the Beam?
